# Change Background Color in Hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Goal:
Make the th of "#" and "Firstname" to have background color yellow in hover

Problem:
I do not know how to solve it.

Information:
In this context I cannot use `<thead>` and `<body>` and I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery.

```css
.makeThisOpacity {
    opacity: 0;
}
.makeThisOpacity: hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th class="makeThisOpacity">#</th>
            <th class="makeThisOpacity">>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `I do not know how to solve it.` Well, firstly you should have think to make element visible in some way then...

Comment: opacity: 0; makes an element fully transparent, rendering it invisible in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.makeThisOpacity` is having `opacity: 0,` on hover change it to 1

Try this,

```
.makeThisOpacity {
    opacity: 0;
}
.makeThisOpacity:hover { 
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: `opacity: 0;` makes an element fully transparent, rendering it invisible in the process.

Comment: @connexo But still handling any mouse event, see e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/ybvvwaop/

Comment: Sure, noone stated that it does not.

Comment: @connexo So i didn't understand your former comment. So what did you mean?

Comment: It was directed towards the OP to understand what he's doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity: 0 will make the text fully invisible.

```
.makeThisOpacity {
    opacity: 0;// remove it
}

.makeThisOpacity:hover { 
     background-color: yellow;
     //if you want to use opacity as 0 then to display it increase your opacity, or else remove it.
     opacity: 0.5; // remove if your initial opacity is not 0.

}
```